# Create sum of row values in SQL report builder

Tags: sql, sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I need to create a report in SCCM with the SQL report builder. Currently the report shows every application from every user on every client in a separate row (which is fine).

But I also need a function which shows me the total number of launch counts for each application (identified by ID number).

Current report output:

[image: Output of the report]

So the end result which I need should be:

```
ID        Manufacturer        Name         Filename          LaunchCountTotal
32        7-zip               7-zip        7z.exe            543
```

Current report builder layout:

[image: Current report builder layout]

This is the query which is used for the dataset:

```
select diin_applications_table.manufacturer, diin_applications_table.id, diin_applications_table.name, diin_applications_table.version, diin_applications_table.filename, RecentlyUsedApps_DATA_prod.LaunchCount00, RecentlyUsedApps_DATA_prod.LastUsedTime00, RecentlyUsedApps_DATA_prod.LastUserName00, System_DATA_prod.Name0
from diin_applications_table
INNER JOIN RecentlyUsedApps_DATA_prod ON diin_applications_table.Filename=RecentlyUsedApps_DATA_prod.ExplorerFileName00
INNER JOIN System_DATA_prod ON
RecentlyUsedApps_DATA_prod.MachineID=System_DATA_prod.MachineID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with a `CTE` as can be seen below:

```
with cte as (
select diin_applications_table.manufacturer, diin_applications_table.id, diin_applications_table.name, diin_applications_table.version, diin_applications_table.filename, RecentlyUsedApps_DATA_prod.LaunchCount00, RecentlyUsedApps_DATA_prod.LastUsedTime00, RecentlyUsedApps_DATA_prod.LastUserName00, System_DATA_prod.Name0
from diin_applications_table
INNER JOIN RecentlyUsedApps_DATA_prod ON diin_applications_table.Filename=RecentlyUsedApps_DATA_prod.ExplorerFileName00
INNER JOIN System_DATA_prod ON
RecentlyUsedApps_DATA_prod.MachineID=System_DATA_prod.MachineID
)

select
    ID
,   Manufacturer
,   [Name]
,   [FileName]
,   sum(LaunchCount) LaunchCountTotal
from    cte
group by    ID
,           Manufacturer
,           [Name]
,           [FileName]
```

Hope this helps.